# Unable to start mongod process on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Whenever I am trying to run the process it's showing this error.

**Error message:**
[image]

Comment: Those are are the _log_ messages you get when you start the `mongod` (MongoDB Server). How did you start the server? You can check with `ps` if the `mongod` is up and running. You can configure to use a log file, etc., and run the mongod as background process. Check your MongoDB Manual.

Comment: I checked `mongod` is not running. @prasad_

Comment: I usually use `sudo systemctl enable mongod` command to automatically start the service on startup.
But this time when I checked the status of mongod service it's showing failed.

Comment: This is more a suggestion than an answer, I would recommend you to use docker containers for MongoDB as they are easy to maintain configure and throw away once done.

Comment: How did you get to see those messages you had posted? You ran some command and then those messages showed - what is that command?

Comment: @prasad_ I used `mongod` command.